# Why does this implementation of QuickSort not work?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I tried to translate the Quicksort code from Java to Python but it didnt work. Can someone tell me where the Problem is? I'm getting a "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" but with my example I only want to order less than 10 integers so I dont think this is the real problem...

```py
def help(array, low, high):
    pivot = array[low]
    fromhigh = high
    fromlow = low
    while True:
        while(array[fromhigh]>pivot):
            fromhigh = fromhigh-1
        while(array[fromlow]<pivot):
            fromlow = fromlow+1
        if(fromlow<fromhigh):
            array[fromlow], array[fromhigh] = array[fromhigh], array[fromlow]
        else:
            return fromhigh


def quickSort(array, low, high):
   if (low<=high):
       pivot = help(array, low, high)
       quickSort(array, low, pivot)
       quickSort(array, pivot + 1, high)


#Testarray
array = [10, 7, 2 , 8, 9, 1, 5, 11, 13]
n = len(array)
quickSort(array, 0, n-1)
print("Sorted Array:")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % array[i]),
```

Comment: in help function there is no condition when you wil get out of the while statement , so you need to add condition there that when fromlow>fromhigh thn exit while loop else swap element

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `print(low, high)` at the beginning of your `quickSort` function, you'll notice that it prints `0 0` all the time until it crashes.

The `if` condition there is incorrect. Instead of `low <= high` it should be `low < high`, because you don't want to continue sorting a single-element subarray.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Do you have an idea how i can change the code, so that also same numbers will be sorted?

Comment: @KilianKunkel you can see this for help : [help1](https://ideone.com/NFGKEY) and [help2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/)